# Убрать анимацию перехода навигации между лаптопом и планшетом

Tags: css

Верстал сайт по принципу mobile first. Сделал бургер меню, использую его на телефонах и планшетах. Я спрятал данное меню за предел экрана слева и по нажатию на бургер - "выезжает". На ноутбуках,через медиа запрос, я убираю бургер, а поля меню я выстраиваю в ряд в `<header>`. Для красивой анимации появления бургер меню я задал `transition 1s`. Когда я уменьшаю экран браузера с размера ноутбука до планшета, посреди экрана появляется данное меню и за 1 секунду "уезжает" за пределы экрана. Как мне сделать так, чтобы transition стал равен 0 только при переходе?

Comment: A в js .onresize был ...

Answer (score 0):

Создай промежуточную ширину в медиа запросе и укажи настройку.

Comment: Пробовал, но если уменьшать дальше, всё равно появляется меню